# Flex mx:TextArea cut-off font

Tags: apache-flex, fonts, textarea, clip, flex-mx

Flex mx TextArea cuts off font glyphs near bounds:

[image]

This is fixed in spark TextArea, but i need to avoid this mask in mx component.

Any ideas?

Comment: What Flex SDK are you using?

Comment: 3.6, 4.5.1 - effect the same. This is mx:TextArea

Comment: a work around may be adding padding?

Comment: adding padding is a patch i use now, but it has 2 disadvantages: 1) i do not know how long font would come out 2) paddings around the TextArea will catch mouse events as TextArea